# How to 'lock' database rows being processed

Tags: ruby, database, multithreading, algorithm, language-agnostic

I have a database filled with rows and multiple threads that are accessing these rows, inputting some of the data from them in a function, producing an output, and then filling the row's missing columns with the output.

Here's the issue: Each row has an `unprocessed` flag which is, by default, true. So each thread is looking for rows with this flag. But each thread is getting the SAME row, it turns out...because the row is being marked as processed after the thread's job is complete, which may happen after a few seconds.

One way I avoided this was to insert a `currently_processed` flag for each row, mark it as false, and once a thread accesses the row, change it to true. Then when the thread is done, just change if back to false. The problem with this is that I have to use some sort of locking and not allow any other thread to do anything until this occurs. I was wondering if there's an alternative approach where I wouldn't have to do thread locking (via a mutex or something) and thus slow down the whole process.

If it helps, the code is in Ruby, but this problem is language agnostic, but here's the code to demonstrate the type of threading I'm using. So nothing special, threading on the lowest level like almost all languages have:

```
3.times do
  Thread.new do
   row = get_database_row
   result = do_some_processing(row)
   insert_results_into_row(result)
  end
end.each(&:join)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "real" answer here is that you need a **database transaction**. When one thread gets that row, then the **database** needs to know that this row is currently up for processing.

You can't resolve that within your application! You see, when two threads look at the same row at the same time, they could **both** try to write that flag ... and yep, it for sure changes to "currently processed"; and then both threads will update row data and write that back. Maybe that is not the problem if any processing results in the **same** final result; but if not, then all kinds of data integrity problems will arise.

So the real answer is that you step back and look how your specific database is designed in order to deal with such things.

Comment: While in a trasanction, the other threads will have to wait, right? I don't see how is this different than a mutex. Ofc, it's at a database level, but is there any functional difference?

Comment: Your *mutex* is something that lives in your application. As written: you can't assume that two reads reading than writing that field **into** the database will lead to correct results. Yes, you dont need to use the database, but the point is: that is one of the points of using a database - having that level of control. You see, you are simply suggesting to **re-invent** the wheel here within your application. You chances are: you will get that wrong.

Comment: @anemaria20: A real mutex would work but your original description of `currently_processed` flag would not work. The `currently_processed` flag may LOOK like a mutex but a mutex has an additional property: there are low-level guarantees that no two threads can set a mutex simultaneously. Similarly transactions is a DB feature that provide such guarantees. So transactions is basically how databases provide mutex-like capabilities

Comment: @anemaria20: Additional note: mutexes can only work inside a single machine. Transactions work if you have several different machines talking to the database (for example, if you use load-balancers)

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there's an alternative approach where I wouldn't have to do thread locking (via a mutex or something) and thus slow down the whole process.

There are some ways to do this:

1) One common dispatcher for all threads. It should read all rows and put them into shared queue from where processing theads will get rows.

2) Go deeper into DB, find out if it supports something like oracles's "select for update skip locking" syntax and utilize it. For oracle you need to use his syntax in cursor and make somewhat cumbersome interaction, but at least it can work this way.

3) Partition input by, say, index of worker thread. So 1st worker out of 3 will only process rows 1,4,7 etc. 2nd worker will only process rows 2, 5, 8 etc.